# BarCodeScanner in Android not able to make proper entry in manifest.xml

Tags: android

Hi i am developing an application that needs to have its own barcode scanner, for this i am using this tutorial 
 http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.in/2011/12/installing-barcode-plugin-for-phonegap.html

I had successfully imported library project and sample code to my workspace and its running very well , however when i am trying to add this sample code to my project,i got errors. Actually i want to open barcode scanner on a button click , but it gives following errors

```
01-23 11:57:42.642: E/AndroidRuntime(8426): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
```

Here is My button click event code :

```
btnScan.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Intent it =new Intent(mContext,BarcodeScanner.class);
                 startActivity(it);
            }
        });
```

and this is my Manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.adisoft.newtodolist"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
<supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />


    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <permission
        android:name="com.adisoft.newtodolist.supportmapfragment.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
        android:protectionLevel="signature" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.adisoft.newtodolist.ActivityListItem"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.adisoft.newtodolist.ActivityTest"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.adisoft.newtodolist.ActivityMap"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.adisoft.newtodolist.MapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.adisoft.newtodolist.ActivityMyCategory"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.adisoft.newtodolist.ActivityCategoryDetail"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

         <activity android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner" android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
           <!--  <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter> -->
        </activity>
        <!-- ZXing activities --> 
        <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" 
            android:exported="false"> 
            <intent-filter> 
               <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN"/> 
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity> 
        <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity" 
            android:label="@string/share_name"> 
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.ENCODE"/> 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>




        <receiver
            android:name="com.adisoft.newtodolist.AlarmReciever"
            android:process=":remote" />

        <!-- Goolge Maps API Key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="AIzaSyDlWf80cFnMUYRMIq7x4kkG8w_19RDFQRU" />
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

and this is sample projects manifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
       Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
       or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
       distributed with this work for additional information
       regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
       to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
       "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
       with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at

         http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

       Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing,
       software distributed under the License is distributed on an
       "AS IS" BASIS, WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY
       KIND, either express or implied.  See the License for the
       specific language governing permissions and limitations
       under the License.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
      package="com.simonmacdonald.scan" android:versionName="1.1" android:versionCode="5" android:hardwareAccelerated="true">
    <supports-screens
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true"
        android:anyDensity="true"
        />

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_VIDEO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />   
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />


    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        android:debuggable="true">
        <activity android:name=".BarcodeScanner" android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar"
                android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <!-- ZXing activities --> 
        <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" 
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" 
            android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" 
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen" 
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysHidden" 
            android:exported="false"> 
            <intent-filter> 
               <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.SCAN"/> 
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity> 
        <activity android:name="com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity" 
            android:label="@string/share_name"> 
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.ENCODE"/> 
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Please check the Thread which might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9129106/solve-run-time-errors

Comment: i had already seen that thread but not able to understand what i am doing wrong in my case

Comment: Just try to remove the `BarcodeScanner ` declaration as activity from your manifest and then check.

Comment: i think the following is a good point for you http://stackoverflow.com/a/5604598/1809221

Comment: @GrIsHu : its not working it gives activity not found exception...

Comment: @Manu Zi: i want barcode scanner of my own application not from third party application

Comment: ok, then try this: http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/

Comment: @ Manu Zi: please try to help me on this issue, not change my path

Comment: why have you declared your barcode scanner activity as 'com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner' when you can simply declare it as an Activity.

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj : i have put up BarcodeScanner actvity on my main package, but again it gives same error...

Comment: what is the name of your package

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj: com.adisoft.newtodolist and had made changes in manifest.xml file of my project

Comment: but in your manifest it is declared as `<activity android:name="com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner.BarcodeScanner" android:label="@string/app_name"` ?

Comment: @SahilMahajanMj: after your comment , i had made changes in manifest.xml and run the code, again same error

Comment: could you please post the code how you have declared the barcodeScanner class in your manifest, because here it is still the same.